# How to use variable instead of column reference in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, select

I have the following stored procedure.

How can I use a variable (`@selection`) instead of col1, esp. where referring to this as a.col1 ?

```
AS
BEGIN
    @selection nvarchar(100)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT col1, total_count,
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM LogTable
       WHERE Category LIKE '2014-04%' AND col1=a.col1 AND col2=col3
      ) AS match_count,
      (100*match_count/total_count) AS match_percentage
    FROM (
      SELECT col1, COUNT(*) AS total_count
      FROM LogTable
      WHERE Category LIKE '2014-04%'
      GROUP BY col1
    ) a
END
```

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL to solve this in general (that is, create the SQL as a string and then use `sp_executesql` to execute it).

Comment: Thanks. I know that I just need to know how I can combine this with the a. Would I just write a.[@selection] for this (I know how to do the rest to make it dynamic) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your query isn't even syntactically correct (you can't define and use `match_count` at the same level).  I think the following is an equivalent and simpler query:

```
      SELECT col1, COUNT(*) AS total_count,
             SUM(case when col2 = col3 then 1 else 0 end) as match_count
             100*AVG(case when col2 = col3 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as match_percent
      FROM LogTable
      WHERE Category LIKE '2014-04%'
      GROUP BY col1;
```

Here is the dynamic SQL (or a good approximation thereof):

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @selection nvarchar(100);
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

    SET @sql = N'
SELECT <col1>, COUNT(*) AS total_count,
       SUM(case when col2 = col3 then 1 else 0 end) as match_count
       100*AVG(case when col2 = col3 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as match_percent
FROM LogTable
WHERE Category LIKE '2014-04%'
GROUP BY <col1>';

    SET @sql = replace(@sql, '<col1>', @selection);

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END;
```